# How to loop through files in directory with order

Tags: bash

I would like to loop through a directory with a certain order. Let 's say I have files named 1,2,3,4 in the directory.
When I use this for loop in bash `for i in *;` , I get this order 1,2,3,4. How can I change it to get the other order 4,3,2,1

Comment: what's the programming language that you use? anyway you need to sort them before enter the loop

Comment: What is the purpose of doing this ?

Comment: Quick and dirty: `for i in $(ls -Ar); do echo $i; done`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will allow you to loop through all the files in the directory where the ls command is executed in reverse order

for file in $(ls | sort -r); do echo $file; done

Answer (score 1):

You could use `sort -nr`, e.g.

```
ls | sort -nr | xargs -n 1 <command>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pipe the output of `ls` to `sort`

```
for i in `ls | sort -r`
```